# How Do I Script a Database To a Text File So That It Can Be Created Again By Anyone?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database that I have created using SQL Server Developer 2008.

I want to script it to a file so that it can be recreated by anyone at any time.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recreate the structure, right-click on the database and use Tasks --> Generate Scripts.  Walk your way through the wizard, selecting those objects that you want to have created by your script.  This TechNet [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx) will serve as a good starting point for exploring how to do this if the process isn't obvious.

If you need both structure and data, you might want to consider using the [Red Gate SQL Packager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Packager/index.htm) to script the data.

Comment: Microsoft should really have provided a comprehensive set of tools for that. That being said I do like Red Gate's products.

Comment: @Stuart -- I looked through the wizard documentation briefly and didn't see that option.  What step in the wizard is it?  I'd like to update my answer.

Comment: It's in the "Choose Script Options" section, under "Table/View Options"

Comment: @Stuart - I don't see at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186472.aspx) and I don't have access to a 2008 instance so I guess I'll leave the answer as stands with your comments to provide context.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps at Pinal's site. Be careful to select all the options you want:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/

Comment: Sometimes Sql Server 2008 doesn't script all objects if more than one category is selected: it's safer to do tables, then stored procedures, then views etc.

Comment: Do you have any source on this? Thanks.

Comment: Just my own personal experience.. it certainly happened regularly, back when I was using scripts to move things around a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try DBSourceTools. 
http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com
Its open source, and will script an entire database 
- tables, views, procs and data to disk, and then allow you to re-create that database through a deployment target.
It's specifically designed to help developers get their databases under source code control.